# How can I kill a formatting operation launched by the Disks application?

Tags: disk, format

I launched a formatting operation on a drive, asking the Disks application to overwrite all content on the drive. This process is taking too long. How should I kill the process? Closing the Disks application has not stopped the writing operation.

Comment: All you can do is reboot the machine.

Comment: Killing the formatting operation by rebooting the machine, particularly by force-booting (holding down the power button. for example) may permanently damage the disk being formatted and leave it in an unusable state.

Comment: @David from command line gracefully killing the process  is not an option? and yes rebooting can damage the system. just depends on when you do it.